# django-filters compatability issue with Django 2.1

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-2.1

I was upgrading a Django app from 1.8 to 2.1. The app was already using django-filters 0.11.0. As part of upgradation, django-filter has been upgraded to 2.0.0 and Django to 2.1.2.
But when starting the app getting the following error

```
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

The error disappears if I remove the django-filters from the installed app list.

Any idea what's causing this issue? from the documentation, these versions seem compatible

Comment: can you add the error traceback?

Answer (score 0):

As a way to diagnose the origin of the problem run `manage.py check` and see if you find something there.